# C scanning input strings saves to wrong variable

Tags: c, string, scanf

I'm trying to scan 3 strings on the console in C with scanf, but every time the second string is scanned it will also be added at the end of the first one.

I already tried to change the scanf format parameter `(%8s, %[^\n]s, %8[^\n]s)` but nothing worked that well. It seems that `%8s` ignores the second `scanf` and jumps directly to the third one.

```
char matrikelnumber[S_MATRIKELNUMBER]; //S_MATRIKELNUMBER is 8
char first_name[S_FIRST_NAME]; //S_FIRST_NAME is 30
char last_name[S_LAST_NAME]; //S_LAST_NAME is 30

printf("Matrikelnummer: ");
scanf("%s", matrikelnumber);

printf("%s\n", matrikelnumber); //Prints the correct input

printf("Vorname: ");
scanf("%s", first_name);

printf("%s\n", matrikelnumber); //Prints matrikelnumber + first_name added at the end

printf("Nachname: ");
scanf("%s", last_name);
```

If I type in `12345678` for `matrikelnumber` and `Name` for `last_name` the first `printf` prints the correct string while the second one prints `12345678Name`.

How can I save all 3 strings correctly in the corresponding variable?

Comment: Please show sample input.

Comment: @Yunnosch Added to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, strings are terminated by a `\0` character. If your `matrikelnumber` is supposed to be 8 digits long, you need 9 chars to store it: 8 for its contents, plus 1 for the ending `\0`.

Just change this line:

```
char matrikelnumber[S_MATRIKELNUMBER + 1]; //S_MATRIKELNUMBER is 8
```

The reason this happens:

```
printf("%s\n", matrikelnumber); //Prints matrikelnumber + first_name added at the end
```

is that matrikelnumber is read and stored, taking up 8+1 characters, and the `\0` at the end is stored after the end of that array, which happens to coincide with the location of

```
char first_name[S_FIRST_NAME]; //S_FIRST_NAME is 30
```

Then you read the first name, which is stored in that location and its first character overwrites the `\0` that was stored there previously. So, when you're now printing `matrikelnumber`, `printf` keeps outputting until it finds a `\0`: the one that previously marked the end of `matrikelnumber` has been erased and `first_name` is immediately after, and this string does have a `\0` at the end.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I already tried this. But now i found my error: I also save the strings in a struct and here I also have to increase the size of my strings by 1. Pretty dumb mistake on my part... Thanks!